# Flex Datagrid Editable In runtime

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, advanceddatagrid

in my flex application i have a datagrid as 2 columns editable and remaining columns are non editable. in some condition, in runtime i have to change the editable column to non editable...how can i do this?? any suggestions??
Heres my code...

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adg1" editable = "true" designViewDataType="tree">
                        <mx:columns>
                                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" editable ="true"/>
                                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Age" dataField="age" editable ="true"/>
                                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Roll No" dataField="num" editable = "false"/>
                        </mx:columns>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Thanxx in advance..

Comment: in AS3 script do this (adg1.columns[0] as AdvancedDataGridColumn).editable = false; //for the first column.  You can replace the index for getting other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
You can loop through columns, and check editable property:

```
            for (var i:int = 0; i < adg1.columns.length; i++) 
            {
                if (adg1.columns[i] is AdvancedDataGridColumn)
                {
                    var myCol:AdvancedDataGridColumn = adg1.columns[i] as AdvancedDataGridColumn;

                    trace(myCol.editable);  

                    //for example, change Age column to non editable
                    if (myCol.headerText == 'Age')
                    {
                        myCol.editable = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Method 2:**

if you set id for column like:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="ageCol" headerText="Age" dataField="age" editable ="true"/>
```

you can access it this way:

```
trace("before ageCol editable:",ageCol.editable);

var indx:int = adg1.columns.indexOf(ageCol);
adg1.columns[indx].editable = false;

trace("after ageCol editable:",ageCol.editable);
```

or if it is applicable, just do:

```
ageCol.editable = false;
```

Comment: use dataField in IF condition for the first method.. headerText is  subjected to change more often

Comment: @Kamal Well, I think he got that :) thanks for comment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**adg1.columns** ll return you **array of the columns**.

loop through columns casting each into **AdvancedDataGridColumn** 
and check condition with 'dataField' and make it editable or noneditable as you wish.